# C# While won't enter with true condition

Tags: c#, while-loop

I have a bit of a problem with my c# code.

I have a while loop:

```
while(current.parent != null)
{
      solution.Add(current.move);
      current = current.parent;
}
```

All of the variables have values, but for some reason it doesn't enter the while.

I placed a break at the while and see that the parent property is not null, but it just skips the entire while.

Any ideas why? or how I can modify this to work?

Comment: Why ask us? The debugger is the tool to help you! Obviously you are not testing current but current.parent and if it were not null the loop would be entered..

Comment: If the code doesn't enter the loop, it's either because you're wrong about `current.parent` not being `null`, or wrong that this is the code that's executing (debugging without rebuilding could cause this). Either way, there needs to be a lot more info to make this answerable.

Comment: before the while, use `Console.Write()` to output the contents of `current.parent`.  It will either indicate that the value is null, or it won't output anything (meaning this code isn't actually run).

Comment: I've known debuggers in the past to have bad hover behaviors. Like if you hover over `parent` expecting current.parent it might show you this.parent instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing that every node in the tree had a null value (but the properties of the node weren't), I changed everything to work with the Node's properties instead, which finally worked.

Thanks guys =)

Answer (score 2):

Because `current.parent` is null to begin with.

Probably because `current` is the top most in your tree, i.e. has no children. (Or whatever you want to call it)

The code in your question is very vague but I would guess just using

```
solution.Add(current.move);
while(current.parent != null)
{     
      current = current.parent;
      solution.Add(current.move);
}
```

may help.

This may solve the actual problem you are having (other than not knowing how to use a debugger ;))

So here you log the current move always, then log any parent moves.

Maybe look at refactoring this with a do..while loop!!

Comment: The thing is the entire tree is populated. It's not that I don't know how to use the debugger, everything has a value assigned to it and the first iteration where its supposed to enter the while is a leaf of the tree. I checked and the only node without a parent is the root, but it doesn't enter for a child of the root, for which I know has a value.

It is supposed to work, but for some reason it's not entering it. In the debugger I can see the condition for the loop is true, but it doesn't enter.

Guess I can try changing it to a do..while. Hopefully that works =)

Comment: Just rechecked everything. Apparently nothing has a value. 
Even after I assign a value (which is not null) to a specific child and output that child, that child is apparently null. I don't know how..

Comment: Finally got it working again. Not sure why but the Node (child) was null, but it's properties aren't. So just changed everything to work with the properties instead. But thanks anyway guys..